# What kind of antique WWI aircraft model is this? Inventor's prototype?

Tags: aircraft-identification, model-aircraft, biplane

I've discovered an interesting WWI era model of an aircraft and I am trying to find out what could it be. It is 29" long and it looks like not a hobby model, but an inventor's prototype. I love the idea of the extra fuel tank above the cockpit. It connects with a bigger fuel tank near the engine. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Personally, I am not sure that above the cockpit there is a fuel tank, looks like an attachment for the top wing

Comment: The unusual shape is similar to a Curtiss Carrier Pigeon.

Comment: Hi Federico! There is a fuel tank at the very top. A small pipe is going down connecting it with a bigger size tank near the engine. I will try to upload more photos.

Comment: OK, uploaded! It is definitely an extra fuel tank.

Comment: Yes, the shape is similar to Pigeon! I believe it just does not look like just a mail carrier. I can see the round-shaped aim near the cockpit, which means the plane was likely designed for a battle.

Comment: What about the grid underneath the screw? Is this a sort of a radiator?

Answer (score 2):

Beautiful find..., an original scale model from the 20s.
At first glance, the rudder is a typical "Sturtevant" design..., but the rest of the fuselage appears to be from another aircraft, or a type of Sturtevant that I am not familiar with. It could also be a free work, a personal design by the modeler... It looks like an old rudder concept for a "modern" fuselage design.

[image: Sturtevant S-4]

[image: Sturtevant S-2]

Sturtevant S-4

Sturtevant S-2

Answer (score 1):

Some details suggest that the builder wasn't trying to faithfully model a particular airplane, working from detailed diagrams and photographs as one does nowadays a hundred years later, but was instead incorporating elements from various airplanes from personal memory.

- peculiar arrangement of ribs in the fin/rudder
- conical top and bottom panels of cowling, easily soldered from flat metal sheet but rare on manufactured airplanes
- too-deep fuselage: the position of the exhaust stacks and prop shaft
  makes one wonder what would have to be down in the belly.

A few more detailed photos (does the right side also have exhaust stacks?) would help to resolve this.